# Show the interior of $Y = ${$f ∈ X |f(0) = f(1)$} in C[0,1] with uniform norm is empty

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider normed vector space $X = (C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_u)$ ,where $\|\cdot\|_u$ is the uniform norm.

Show that the interior of $Y = \{ f \in X | f(0) = f(1) \}$ is empty.

What I've done:

If $y$ is an interior point, there is some $r > 0$ that $B_r(y)$ is in $Y$.

$B_r(y) = \{ y_1 \in X | \|y(x)-y_1(x)\| < r \}$

Set $y_2(x) = y(x) + rx/2$ (so it is in $B_r(y)$)

$y_2(1) = y(1) + r/2$

$y_2(0) = y(0)$

so $y_2(1) \neq y_2(0)$ ($r > 0$) so there is a point in $B_r(y)$ that is not inside $Y$, so there are no interior points.

Comment: Your proof is fine. Next time, explicit your question (I guess it was "is my proof correct?", or sth like that)

Comment: Yes. If a linear subspace of a normed space  contain a ball then it must be the whole space.